# Caching DOM elements javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

I am trying to cache all the DOM elements on the page intialisation using the following code:

```
init:function(){
      this.cacheDom();      
    }

cacheDom:function(){
       var that = this;
       this.$jsTabs              = this.container.find('.js-tabs');
       this.$li                  = $jsTabs.find('.tabs').find('li');
       this.$filterBodyTr   =  that.container.find('#filter_body').find("tr");
       this.$customRuleInfo = that.container.find('#custom_rule_info');

    },

enableTabs :function() {

     this.$li.click(function(){
      var index  = this.$li.index(this);
      this.$jsTabs.tabs().select(index);
      if(index==2){
        ****var tr = this.$filterBodyTr;****
        tr.each(function(){
            $t = $(this);
            if($t.is(":visible")){
                if ($t.text().toUpperCase().indexOf("MY NAME") > -1){
                    ****this.$customRuleInfo.addClass("hide-data");****
                }
            }
        });
      }

  });
},
```

Here `this.$filterBodyTr` and `this.$customRuleInfo` remains undefined in lines marked with **** in enableTabs function. I tried using `this` instead of `that` to find the element but it always shows undefined.

Here is the html code referring the elements

```
<table class="table-compressed" id = "js_filter_sort">
        <colgroup>
             <col class="column-lg-3">
             <col class="column-lg-1">
             <col class="column-lg-4">
             <col class="column-lg-2">
             <col class="column-lg-2">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody id = "filter_body"> </tbody>
 </table>



<div class= "row gutter-0 clear text-left padding-left-20 padding-right-20 padding-bottom-20 padding-top-20 hide-data" id = "custom_rule_info">                                               
                                        </div>
```

How can I cache those 2 elements marked with ****. If I don't cache the elements and intialise `var that=this;` inside enableTabs function it works perfectly fine.

Comment: The `this` inside the `click` callback is not the same as outside. You need to cache it with a `that` and change the references within the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the reference to `this` changes and points to something else, as such:

- in the `click` function is a reference to the DOM element which triggered the event
- in the `each` function is a reference of the current element you're iterating over

One practice is to save a reference to `this` in another variable - usually called `self`- and this will be available as a closure inside the other methods. To better understand how the context changes, have a look over [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply).

In the meantime, try this:

```
init:function(){
  this.cacheDom();      
}

cacheDom:function(){
   this.$jsTabs         = this.container.find('.js-tabs');
   this.$li             = $jsTabs.find('.tabs').find('li');
   this.$filterBodyTr   =  that.container.find('#filter_body').find("tr");
   this.$customRuleInfo = that.container.find('#custom_rule_info');
},

enableTabs :function() {
  var self = this
  this.$li.click(function(){
    var index  = self.$li.index(this);
    self.$jsTabs.tabs().select(index);
    if(index==2){
      var tr = self.$filterBodyTr;
      tr.each(function(){
        $t = $(this);
        if($t.is(":visible")){
          if ($t.text().toUpperCase().indexOf("MY NAME") > -1){
           self.$customRuleInfo.addClass("hide-data");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Using this code `this.$li` is seen undefined to enableTabs function however is available in cacheDom function. I replaced `$jsTabs.find('.tabs').find('li');` with `this.$jsTabs.find('.tabs').find('li');` I keep getting `Cannot read property 'index' of undefined`

Comment: I told you that `this` changes scope. Make sure you're referring to the current scope according to your application's logic. If inside the `click()`, this is the element that was clicked, inside the `each` is the current element of the iteration. Make sure you use it correctly.

PS: I have edited the answer, try it now!